# Force Requests For Image Files Through API With .htaccess and Mod Rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a web application run on an Apache server. I utilize an .htaccess file for various redirects and would like to add a redirect for all requests for image files. If the identification is as simple as having a ".png" or similar file extension that will suffice. For all of these requests I would like to redirect to a url such as:
http://example.com/imape_api?url=http://original.url/image.png
I plan to process all images before serving them to the user. The processing includes watermarking, compressing and resizing.

Comment: OK, sounds like a plan, so what is your actual question?

Comment: Since you already have implemented "various redirects" we assume you know how that stuff works. So why can't you simply implement another internal rewrite for those image requests?